# python - multithreading -- join() method

Tags: python, multithreading, join, exit

```
import threading, time

class test(threading.Thread):                 

    def __init__(self,name,delay):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.delay = delay

    def run(self):
        c = 0
        while True:
            time.sleep(self.delay)            
            print 'This is thread %s on line %s' %(self.name,c)
            c = c + 1 
            if c == 15:
                print 'End of thread %s' % self.name
                break

one = test('one', 1).start()
two = test('two', 3).start()

one.join()
two.join()

print 'End of main'
```

Problem: cannot get join() methods to work properly, gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)line 29, in <module> join() NameError: name 'join' is not defined
```

if i remove:

```
one.join
two.join
```

the code works perfectly fine.

I wanted to print the last line,

```
print 'End of main'
```

after the two threads have ended. I can't seem to understand why join() is not an attribute of the two instances?

Comment: sorry -- newbie here. I tried

Comment: I mean just in your post. I think your program looks different, otherwise you wouldn't have come that far.

Comment: Yes I know what you mean. I could not get it right. I know it is 4 spaces indentation. Like for e.g. below the actual code for the rest of the code blocks I have managed to get it right. Don't know why that is.

Comment: The edit of @atabrizi looks not good either. I will try.

Comment: Was not fast enough, but that's it.

Comment: This is actually my first post on this site and I am impressed. Great work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
one = test('one', 1).start()
two = test('two', 3).start()
```

Your problem is that `start()` doesn't do a `return self`. `one` and `two` are not threads. They're `None` or whatever the return value of `start()` actually is.

This works:

```
one = test('one', 1)
one.start()
two = test('two', 3)
two.start()
```

Comment: You both beat me. SO says 23 seconds!

Comment: That is great!! Did not realise it was more to do with the RETURN, I was focused more on code shortening. anyways thanks